# Cross-posting etiquette

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

Is it okay to copy a previous post from Stack Overflow, in the interests of building questions during the beta stage of Code Review?

I'm perfectly happy with the answers I received for the question over on Stack Overflow. It would not be 100% identical, as one of the respondents found a bug. So I'd post code with the bug fix and perhaps some slight re-wording, but it would still be of the form of "Is there a better way of doing this?"

Of course once Code Review left beta, this would be unnecessary duplication. It seems that the beta currently needs more questions to build it, that is all.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicated (or very closely related to): http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87/list-of-stackoverflow-questions-to-migrate

Comment: No not a duplicate as such, but it definitely comes under that thread. So it looks like the post in question should be retagged with the "code-review" tag and it will be migrated over on its own.

Answer (score 2):

This question dates back from CR's debut, and it being unanswered on the front page is just weird. Nevertheless, it's a good question so here's my input.

#### Code Review Questions on StackOverflow

These questions ought to be migrated over here, as mentioned in a comment. While there is no "official" migration route from SO to CR while the site is in beta, when you're browsing SO and notice a question that would be a good fit for CodeReview, you should leave a comment on the SO post telling the OP about this site (ideally with a link), keeping in mind this section of our [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> To be on-topic the answer **must be yes to *all* questions:**
>
> - Does my question contain code? (Please include the code in the question, not a link to it)
> - Did I write that code?
> - Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> - Do I want the code to be good code, (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> - To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?
> - Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?

Ideally these questions should be [flagged for moderator attention to be migrated to CR](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/should-quick-fixes-to-non-working-code-go-into-comments-only/797#797), as flagging for moderator is the only way questions can be migrated from SO (at least until CR blooms out of beta).

---

#### Code from StackOverflow Answers

One thing that hasn't been addressed here, is whether the code in *answers* of some StackOverflow questions could be subject to code review. I think some SO answers *can* be reposted on CR, just as long as the SO answer is a code-centric answer that is:

- Authored by the same person that posts the CR question.
- Self-contained as a working solution.
- Answering the SO question with *real*, working code.

I'm guilty of two such questions. In both cases, I wrote an answer on StackOverflow, for which I wanted to get the code peer reviewed.

Comment: So if I ask for a review of code contained in one of my answers on Stack Overflow or Software Engineering SE, would that be in violation of site policy?

Comment: @EJoshuaS cross-posting implies *questions*, not answers =)