# Should quick fixes to non-working code go into comments only?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, answers

I've started thinking about this after seeing the answer for [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29410/why-does-my-code-not-append-the-variable-like-it-should-python) question.

Of course, non-working code shouldn't be posted here.  However, there are times where someone addresses such issues in an answer, with or without a general review.  I'm not discouraging such issues from being fixed, as it's always good to help in any way.  I just think that fixing off-topic issues shouldn't necessarily constitute an *answer* on this site (just as you wouldn't see a code review on SO).  I think they should all be comments instead IF they must be addressed here instead of on SO.

This also got me thinking: should such answers posted anyway be disregarded/ignored, or considered legitimate (if it's helpful of course)?  I *don't* think it's fair to penalize answerers, but I also wish we had the ability to migrate questions so that those answers will become on-topic upon reaching SO.

Now, there's the problem with someone without commenting abilities having a fix, but having to post it as an answer instead.  Should such answers stay, or become comments (requiring moderator intervention)?

What do you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, we moderaters can migrate questions. However, we've been asked only to moderate good questions. What this means is that when someone dumps two pages of code and says "what's wrong with this?" that's not a good stack overflow question. For a good stack overflow question, the OP needs to demonstrate that they've put good effort into figuring out the problem themselves. Many times the off-topic questions here just don't pass that bar.

If you find a question that you think passes that bar, feel free to flag it for moderator attention and we'll migrate if it its a good question.

Secondly, I think people should not be posting help for these questions either as comments or answers. The question is off-topic, either the question should be migrated to where it is on-topic, or it should be closed. We shouldn't reward people for flouting the rules by telling them what is wrong with their code. I don't think we should down-vote the answers, but I would refrain from upvoting them.

Comment: Ah, so you can.  I thought I once remember someone saying that migration *from* beta sites isn't possible, but whatever.  Anyway, just to make sure: flag for migration if *good* (mentioning migration in the message), and vote to close if *bad*?  Also, everyone needs to see this (especially the second point) since I've still seen it happen.  However, if it still happens beyond this point, what do we tell that person?  Or do we just leave it be (no voting in most cases)?

Comment: @Jamal, I recommend voting to close and migrate it if good. As mods we can reopen the question. But we want to encourage all voting as it helps moves us toward leaving beta.

Comment: Alright, I can do that.  I've been doing my part in all areas of voting, too.  Thanks for these clarifications.